# Garbage value being assigned to an element of list after running the looop

Tags: python, list, xlrd

here is the part of the code:

```
import xlrd as xd

import numpy as n

gx = 'dx.xls'

gy = 'dy.xls'

qx = xd.open_workbook(gx)

qy = xd.open_workbook(gy)

qxs = qx.sheet_by_index(0)

qys = qy.sheet_by_index(0)

imx = qxs.nrows

jmx = qys.ncols

pi = round(n.pi , 10)

Tad = pi*.5

x = [[float(0)]*imx]*jmx

for i in range(1,jmx):

          x[i][0]  = x[i-1][0]+qxs.cell_value(0,i-1)
```

and value of `x[0][0]` becomes 945.6.

the `qsx` cell data is nearly constant in all cells which are 8.6609.
please help me and tell me where am I doing it wrong.

Edit:

I am trying to read `.xls` file and using its cell values which contain length differentials (`dx`) to get x coordinate at every index for which, I ran the loop. As I defined a list as `x` and initiated as `x = [[float(0)]*imx]*jmx`. After running the code, it shows no error but the element in list `x[0][0]` is assigned a fixed value `945.6`. This was not suppose to happen as I ran the loop from `i=1` hence starting evaluation from `x[1][0]` and `x[0][0]` is supposed to remain `0.0`. All cell values in `qsx` is approximately same which is `8.6609`.

Comment: what exactly is your problem, where is the error, or what do you want to achieve and is not working? As far as I can see, the value of `x[0][0]` is not the value it should be ? or what is your problem?

Comment: Also can you please reformat your code as blocks of code rather than lines of code. Here is [the official documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) of StackOverflow markdowns :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused here `x = [[float(0)]*imx]*jmx`. It seems that all lists inside list aren't different but referenses of the same list. Try to change the `x` initialization this way and I think it should work:

UPDATE: I've changed the order of i and j for-loops.

```
x = []
for j in range(jmx):
  x.append([])
  for i in range(imx):
    x[j].append(float(0))
```

You can also use this syntax:

```
x = [[0.0 for i in range(imx)] for j in range(jmx)]
```